# How to check the value exists or not according to id in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to check whether the `menu_id` consists the same order or not.

Suppose `menu_id = 1` and `order = 1`.

Then when the user wants to add same order (i.e. `1`), it must show error message.

If not the the value must be saved.

This is submenu table:

```
Schema::create('submenu', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('submenu_id');
    $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
    $table->unsignedInteger('menu_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->tinyInteger('order');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('menu_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('menu')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

I did this to check whether the `menu_id` consists the order or not, however its not working.

Submenu controller -> `addSubmenu()` function:

```
$order = Input::get('order');
$menu = Input::get('menu_id');

if($menu->contains($order)){
    echo "exists";die;
} else {
    echo "no exists";die;
}
```

Comment: In the `addSubmenu()` function, where is the `$menu` variable being set?

Comment: Nevermind I didn't read properly

Comment: The `contains()` method is a `collection` method. The `$menu` variable is only getting the value of the `menu_id` input and not a `collection` instance.

Comment: how to i check this

Comment: First, I think you should be checking through all the submenu's to see which one has an order of what you are looking for. E.g. `Submenu::where('order', $order)->get()`. I assume what you are looking for is how many order parts are on the user's order?

Comment: I want to check whether the menu_id has the same order or not..

Comment: Are `submenu` records `orders`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [laravel eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) to acheive this. Try:

`Submenu::where('order', $order)->where('menu_id', $menu)->get();`